# php always returns error for empty params in postman?

Tags: php, parameters, get, postman

I'm trying to make php get, but it always seems to call haveEmptyParameters.

The call is to getInformation() and that works fine. Just the parameters never seem to go through? Or maybe there is another error?

```
    $app->get('/getinformation', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    if(!haveEmptyParameters(array('field', 'username'), $request, $response)){
        $request_data = $request->getParsedBody(); 
        $field = $request_data['field'];
        $username = $request_data['username'];

        $db = new DbOperations; 
        $result = $db->getInformation($field,$username);

        $response_data = array();
        $response_data['error'] = false; 
        $response_data['users'] = $result; 

        $response->write(json_encode($response_data));

        return $response
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus(200);  
    }


});



function haveEmptyParameters($required_params, $request, $response){
$error = false; 
$error_params = '';
$request_params = $request->getParsedBody(); 

foreach($required_params as $param){
    if(!isset($request_params[$param]) || strlen($request_params[$param])<=0){
        $error = true; 
        $error_params .= $param . ', ';
    }
}

if($error){
    $error_detail = array();
    $error_detail['error'] = true; 
    $error_detail['message'] = 'Required parameters ' . substr($error_params, 0, -2) . ' are missing or empty';
    $response->write(json_encode($error_detail));
}
return $error;


}

$app->run();
```

-----Postman Output of error-------

```
{"error":true,"message":"Required parameters field, username are missing or empty"}
```

Comment: Ignore your entire `haveEmptyParameters` for now and just dump `$request`. Also, is it `getinformation` or `getInformation`

Comment: Ignoring haveEmptyParameters gives me "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" error?

Comment: So is `$request` null then?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It actually looks like no get functions are working, even though posts are. Again this only happens in android studio, postman works fine.